# How can i use ffmpeg.exe command line to create a video file from number of images on hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ffmpeg

In command prompt window i typed in the directory of the images:

D:\SavedScreenshots>ffmpeg.exe  -r 3 -i Imgp%04d.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi

The images file are Bmp type.
The first image file name is: screenshot0.bmp
The last one is: screenshot168.bmp

Example of one image details: Width 1920 Height 1080 Bit Depth 32

The ffmpeg.exe file is in the same directory of the images.

In the prompt windows console ouput i see:

[image2 @ 00000000025624a0] Could find no file with path 'Imgp%04d.bmp' and index in the range 0-4
Imgp%04d.bmp: No such file or directory

Then how should i do it the command line ?

I found the problem and now it's working but it's very strange.

In c# i create the screenshots of my desktop this images on the hard disk i want to create video file from.
In c# i did in a timer tick event:

```
int count = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
            bmp.Save(@"D:\SavedScreenshots\screenshot" + count + ".bmp");
            bmp.Dispose();
            count ++;
        }
```

This saved the images on the hard disk all of them in sizes between 129-132kb each file. I could edit/open the images and see them no problems but ffmpeg could not handle them gave me this error.

Now i changed the code in the c# to this:

```
bmp.Save(@"D:\SavedScreenshots\screenshot" + count + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I added the part: System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp

Now each image file it's size is about 7MB !!!!
And now ffmpeg can handle it with the command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 3 -i screenshot%d.bmp -vf scale=ntsc,setdar=16/9 test.avi
```

I wonder why when the images size was 130KB ffmpeg couldn not handle it didn't find the files or directory and when they are 7MB it does find and create the video file ?

Even now when i type as command line:

```
ffmpeg  -i screenshot%03.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi
```

I'm getting erorr not such file or directory

Only when i type:

```
ffmpeg  -i screenshot%d.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi
```

It's working.

Why when doing screenshot%3.bmp it's not working but screenshot%d.bmp does working ?

Also doing screenshot0.bmp worked. Only screenshot%3.bmp not working.
And in all examples i saw i had to make screenshot%3 or %2 but they give me the error no such directory file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your image files' name are `screenshotxxx.bmp`, the input argument of `ffmpeg` should be  `-i screenshot%3d.bmp`.

Comment: halfelf tried your solution and got same not found file error: ffmpeg.exe  -r 3 -i screenshot%3d.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi and the error: [image2 @ 00000000025b24a0] Could find no file with path 'screenshot%3d.bmp' and index in the range 0-4
screenshot%3d.bmp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

If your filename number sequence don't contain uniform padding, you can use

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 3 -i screenshot%d.bmp -vf scale=ntsc,setdar=16/9 test.avi
```

I assume that you mean to resize to NTSC wide i.e. 720x480 with display aspect ratio of 16:9.

Comment: Mulvya it's not working tried your solution and i got some errors i updated my question with the errors i got.

Comment: Good news: it recognizes all the BMP files `Duration: 00:00:56.33` @ 3 fps = 169 images.Bad news: FFmpeg thinks the images are corrupt. Try `ffplay screenshot0.bmp`. Does the image show?

Comment: I did a test now i typed this: ffmpeg.exe  -r 3 -i screenshot0.bmp -s 720x480 test.avi only one file and it worked. I have avi file with one image i can play the avi file with windows media player. So i can't find where is the problem yet.

Comment: As per the console output, 17 of the images are not recognized as valid BMP files (`[bmp @ 0000000000eb72c0] bad magic number`). Try `ffmpeg -y -framerate 3 -t 1 -i screenshot%d.bmp -vf scale=ntsc,setdar=16/9 test.avi` with increasing values ot `t`, till you get the error.  e.g. if you don't get the error for t=5 but do get it for t=6, then one or more of screenshot15.bmp, screenshot16.bmp and screenshot17.bmp is corrupt or not a BMP.

Comment: Ok i found the problem. It was my mistake. Th screenshots i'm creating with c# and i just gave the files names in the and ".bmp" so all the files was 130 KB i could edit/open and the see the images but the ffmpeg didn't work with it. Now i changed the c# to this: bmp.Save(@"D:\SavedScreenshots\screenshot" + count + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

Comment: After added the System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp part now each image file size is about 7 MB !!! And now the ffmpeg command line is working.

Comment: But it's strange since the smaller size of the images 130KB i could edit them open them see them i got no errors about openning them but ffmpeg couldn't handle them. but now when they are over 7MB each ffmpeg can handle them.

Comment: The earlier images may not have been truly BMPs since BMP is a full raster uncompressed stream and its size will be Width x Height x bytes per pixel, so for 1920x1080x32bits, it should be close to 8MB.